# Download rtmp stream with a link

Tags: web, jwplayer, rtmp

I try to download a mp4 file with a rtmp stream.
I have a player(jwplayer) with a streamer and file (rtmp link) on other server.
I would like to add a link "Download" which launch the download of file.

Have you an idea to make this link ? And how to download file with a rtmp link on website ?

Thanks you all,

Comment: You will need to download the mp4 over HTTP, not RTMP. Otherwise you will need to copy teh stream into an flv (using something like rtmpdump) then transmux.

Comment: ok thanks you, i have to use rtmpdump with exec function and create link for user. I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

As szatmary commented, you cannot download a file over RTMP protocol, since it is a streaming protocol, not a progressive download.